# finish not closing activity opened by a separate application

Tags: android, odk

ExternalApp opens my android application app. Now in my app, I have a button that returns a value to the external app then closes itself so whatever screen in externalapp opened my app is on top.

while no error is thrown, my application's screen remains on top and I cant see if the value has been sent to the calling external app:

```
public void sendBackData() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("value", "user");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

I have tried this.finish() but it made no difference. Basically, after button click calls sendBackData method, I want the application to pass the value user to the calling external application and hide/close the screen.

Comment: Is ExternalApp your app as well or is it a 3rd party app?

Comment: @avalerio it is a third party app.... ODK Collect to be precise.